# Liferay 7.0 Facebook Integration

Tags: facebook, liferay, liferay-7, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

I'm trying to integrate Facebook with Liferay. I have configured all the necessary settings required (Reference : https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/sso-via-facebook). When I click on facebook link from Login Portlet a popup window appears with Facebook app request and credentials to login, as I enter email id and password, it redirects to Liferay home page but does not get logged in.  The following url appears after redirecting  : **[http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home#*=*](http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home#_=_)**

And When I make the facebook app public and try to login then I get below error

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 191,
  "fbtrace_id": "GQI8Z8xFfoB"
}
}
```

Any idea why user is not getting logged in? Am I missing any step?

Liferay version : 7.0 GA3

Comment: Please [don't crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site)

Answer (score 0):

The answer you  are looking for is on the message itself:

> "Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

Your issue is not on Liferay's side but on your Facebook configuration. All domains you intent to use need to be white-listed on your facebook app page.